# wrap for unspaced languages in emacs

Tags: emacs, text-editors

Emacs has a nice wrapping mode called `visual-line-mode` that is pretty good at sensibly wrapping text. However, it depends almost completely on spaces, which causes the below failure in unspaced languages:

[image: wrapped text]

The above text is supposed to be on the same line.

If I disable `visual-line-mode` and `toggle-truncate-lines`, I get the desired behavior:

[image: truncated text]

Is there a way to tell Emacs to apply one such rule to full-width characters (such as the pictured) and another for half-width characters (i.e. Western text)?

Comment: It would be an even bigger bonus if Emacs could be taught that punctuation should be exempted from wrapping rules.